# AppDomain DoCallBack FileNotFoundException - C#

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a C# 2.0 class with the following code:

```
public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable 
    {
        private string _appName;
        private AppDomain _app;

        public MyClass(string appName)
        {
            _appName = appName;
            _app = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain" + _appName);
            _app.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(CallBackMethod));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(_app);
        }

        public static void CallBackMethod()
        {
            //some operations
        }
    }
```

This class is contained under a Class Library Project, then referenced from a Web Application Project.

So, in my web page I just instance the object, expecting that the constructor of the class would create that new AppDomain and perform the specified operations:

```
MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass("12022012213456");
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.MyClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But the curious thing here is that this exception is happening at this line:

```
_app.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(CallBackMethod));
```

And as you can see, it's happening on **MyClass**, so I don't understand how could it tell me that the assembly could not be found if the code is already being executed??? I just don't get it.

BTW, I'm a newbie at the usage of AppDomain, maybe I'm confused with some concept.

Comment: Can you find out the __app.BaseDirectory and _app.RelativeSearchPath properties right after the _app = AppDomain.Create line?  Each application domain has to resolve its own assemblies.  Think of it as a process within a process.   For some reason or another the new app domain cannot find the assembly,  RelativeSearchPath and BaseDirectory may give some clues.

Comment: @Adam the values are: RelativeSearchPath = null; BaseDirectory = "c:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\", are they good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the AppDomain you created (_app) is having problems locating your `MyClass` class in it's assembly.  Your [CreateDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t89xz0ch.aspx) has not provided any [AppDomainSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) information so it has no context for the current app domains directories nor assemblies.  You have two options, provide a propertly configured `AppDomainSetup` or call `_app.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)` prior to your `DoCallBack` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but the solution was different. In my situation, I needed to explicitly provide my own `AppDomainSetup` object and specify the `ApplicationBase` folder, so that it could actually find my assembly.

My code was loaded by another app, and that's why my assembly wasn't able to be found using the default settings.